# Exception while creating custom object using Salesforce CRUD Metadata API

Tags: java, api, wsdl, salesforce, crm

I am getting the following exception when I try to create a Custom Object in Salesforce, using CRUD Matadata API.

```
     com.sforce.ws.SoapFaultException: Must specify a {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}
 type attribute value for the {http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata}metadata element
        at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.createException(SoapConnection.java:205)
        at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.receive(SoapConnection.java:149)
        at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:98)
        at com.sforce.soap.metadata.MetadataConnection.create(MetadataConnection.java:273)
        at com.sfo.service.SalesforceObjectBootstrap.createCustomObject(SalesforceObjectBootstrap.java:226)
```

I am using the code from this link, The only thing that I changed were the name of the Custom Object
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_calls_intro.htm

The exception occurs at this step

```
AsyncResult[] asyncResults = metadataConnection.create(new CustomObject[]{customObject});
```

The Custom object just before invoking the create method above has the following parameter values.

```
[CustomObject [Metadata  fullName='lead_5273_custom_reg__c'
]
 actionOverrides='{[0]}'
 articleTypeChannelDisplay='null'
 businessProcesses='{[0]}'
 customHelp='hey there help me'
 customHelpPage='null'
 customSettingsType='null'
 customSettingsVisibility='null'
 deploymentStatus='Deployed'
 deprecated='false'
 description='Created from backend Webcast API : Lead 5273 Custom Reg'
 enableActivities='false'
 enableDivisions='false'
 enableEnhancedLookup='false'
 enableFeeds='false'
 enableHistory='false'
 enableReports='false'
 fieldSets='{[0]}'
 fields='{[0]}'
 gender='null'
 household='false'
 label='Lead 5273 Custom Reg'
 listViews='{[0]}'
 nameField='[CustomField [Metadata  fullName='lead_5273_custom_reg__c'
]
 caseSensitive='false'
 customDataType='null'
 defaultValue='null'
 deleteConstraint='null'
 deprecated='false'
 description='field name for a metadata custom object'
 displayFormat='null'
 escapeMarkup='false'
 externalDeveloperName='null'
 externalId='false'
 formula='null'
 formulaTreatBlanksAs='null'
 inlineHelpText='null'
 label='Lead 5273 Custom Reg'
 length='0'
 maskChar='null'
 maskType='null'
 picklist='null'
 populateExistingRows='false'
 precision='0'
 referenceTo='null'
 relationshipLabel='null'
 relationshipName='null'
 relationshipOrder='0'
 reparentableMasterDetail='false'
 required='false'
 restrictedAdminField='false'
 scale='0'
 startingNumber='0'
 stripMarkup='false'
 summarizedField='null'
 summaryFilterItems='{[0]}'
 summaryForeignKey='null'
 summaryOperation='null'
 trackFeedHistory='false'
 trackHistory='false'
 type='Text'
 unique='false'
 visibleLines='0'
 writeRequiresMasterRead='false'
]
'
 namedFilters='{[0]}'
 pluralLabel='Lead 5273 Custom Regs'
 recordTypeTrackFeedHistory='false'
 recordTypeTrackHistory='false'
 recordTypes='{[0]}'
 searchLayouts='null'
 sharingModel='ReadWrite'
 sharingReasons='{[0]}'
 sharingRecalculations='{[0]}'
 startsWith='null'
 validationRules='{[0]}'
 webLinks='{[0]}'
]
```

I used the method mentioned here to generate the WSDL files and its java skeleton.
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_quickstart.htm#topic-title-sample-code

My code exactly matches the example provided above. I simply copy pasted the whole thing.

I found this link, which mentioned the same exception. But this link is relating to creating a Folder.
http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Java-Development/Metadata-API-errors-Must-specify-a-type-attribute-value-for-the/td-p/175253

Please let me know how to solve this problem.

Comment: If you have the time, have a look at the Files Metadata API. Much faster and it only seems more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not played with this myself, but from the looks of the exception, the `MetaData` block here:

```
[CustomObject [Metadata  fullName='lead_5273_custom_reg__c']
```

needs to contain the object type, which I'm assuming in this case is `CustomObject__c` (all custom objects have the `__c` suffix), so maybe try the following:

```
[CustomObject [Metadata  fullName='lead_5273_custom_reg__c' type='CustomObject__c']
```

Unless of course, `fullname` is actually the object name, which could be a possibility.

Comment: you are correct, that is what the error message is implying. But unfortunately, there is no method in the API (Java bean generated from WSDL) which allows me to set the type. And the fact that this is the exact same code shown in their documentation. This makes me to think that I am missing something, but I don't know what.